# How can I pass NOW() function in the array for model argument in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my array for insert the data into the database with table name is `borrow_user` and `NOW()` is use for the `avt_date` field name in `borrow_user` table.

How can I pass `NOW()` function in the array for model argument in codeigniter?

```
$data = array(
                  'user_name'=>$name,user_name is a field name in table 



             'user_father_name'=>$this->input->post('father_name'),//user_father is a field name in table 


            'user_dob'=>$this->input->post('DOB'), //user_dob is a field name in table 


            'user_email'=>$this->input->post('email'), // user_email is a field name in table 


            'user_pass'=>md5($pass),  //user_pass is a field name in table 



            'user_address'=>$this->input->post('address'),



            'phn'=>$this->input->post('phn'),


            'user_type'=>2,

            'avt_date'=>NOW()); //now() function is not working given an error .



        $this->load->model('login_user');


        $regis_id=$this->login_user->regis_b($data);
        //model class code    

public function regis_b($data)
{

    $arr=array('user_email'=>$data['user_email']);


   $this->db->insert('borrow_user', $data);


    $sel_id=$this->db->select('id')
                         ->from('borrow_user')
                          ->where($arr)
                           ->get();


    if($sel_id->num_rows())
    {


        return $sel_id->row()->id;


     }else{


        return FALSE;
    }


}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass an SQL function through the active record insert function like this.

But there are two ways you can get the same result:

**1. Set the timestamp in PHP**

```
'avt_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

**2. Set it just before the insert statement**

You'll need to remove avt_date from your $data array. Insert will group the previous set statements with the data passed in to make one full query.

```
$this->db->set('avt_date', 'NOW()', FALSE);
$this->db->insert('borrow_user', $data);
```

Comment: thanks @Gavin for your contribution .I got my answer